# How does instance-identifier looks like in yang model?

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

AS far as I understand, instance-identifier type has an XPath statement which points to some node is a tree. And what's next? How does instance-identifier identify this node? How do I apply instance-identifier to the node it points to? Or do I get it totally wrong... 
I also don't have any example of this except those found in google like

```
    leaf instance-identifier-leaf {
        type instance-identifier;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An instance-identifier can be a reference to any data node in the system.
Think of it as a pointer; it doesn't contain the data itself, just a reference to it (e.g. an address) 
It is useful for example to represent a reference to an object that is modeled as a YANG container or list instance..

Given that YANG data can be expressed as an XML document, the way you 'point' to a specific element within that is therefore similar to 'pointing' to a specific XML element. The way you do that in XML is by using XPath, which allows to use a

Here's an example:

```
   container a {

      list b {
         key x;
         leaf x { type int8; }

         list c {
            key y;
            leaf y { type int8; }
         }
     }
  }

  leaf ref {
    type instance-identifier;
  }
```

So imagine that a real system has its datastore containing this data (for simplification, I'm using XML format, and ignoring namespaces; a real system doesn't need to keep its datastore in XML format):

```
<a>
  <b>
    <x>1</x>
  </b>
  <b>
    <x>5</x>
    <c>
      <y>1</y>
    </c>
    <c>
      <y>2</y>
    </c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <x>10</x>
    <c>
      <y>5</y>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

So basically we have a bunch of list entries, some of them cascaded.
If you'd represent all these nodes in xpath, you'd get a list with:

```
/a
/a/b[x=1]
/a/b[x=5]
/a/b[x=5]/c[y=1]
/a/b[x=5]/c[y=2]
/a/b[x=10]
/a/b[x=10]/c[y=5]
```

If you had an instance identifier outside this hierarchy called **ref**, it could take any of these xpaths as possible values, as a string value. So it contain a reference to one of those nodes; it would not contain the node itself, just a reference to it.

One final note is that it is not mandatory that the node referenced by the instance-identifier actually exists in the datastore; you can have an instance-identifier that is pointing to a non-existent node. There is a yang statement (requires-instance) that can be added as a substatement of the type statement, that allows to control whether only existing instances can be referenced, or whether non-existing ones can also be accepted.

---

Regarding the format of the value, note that the way the instance-identifier is represented depends on the protocol you are using. An instance identifier in NETCONF is different from one in RESTCONF (although they are very similar). 
You could imagine a CLI to have a custom way to represent YANG objects, for example:

- A data node is defined with the xpath **/a/b[x=5]/c[y=1]**
- In CLI, that node address is viewed as **c-5-1** (just an example)
- If you had an instance-identifier pointing to that object, its value would be the string 'c-5-1' in CLI, but in NETCONF it would still be the xpath.

In short, the format depends on the protocol you are using.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how NETCONF and RESTCONF differ on representation of instance identifiers?  Do you have an example of the same instance identifier, in both NETCONF and RESTCONF representations?

Comment: RESTCONF itself supports multiple types of encoding, particularly XML and JSON.
For XML encoding, it works exactly the same as in NETCONF, e.g. instance-identifiers are displayed as a xpath.
However, for JSON encoding there is a slight simplification; it is still xpath, but given that namespaces in JSON are not as simple, they are for the most part omitted. The definition on how instance-identifiers are encoded in JSON are described in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7951#section-6.11, which contains examples.

Comment: Thanks @Paulo Gomes